# Maintaing a separate non-doc window in a doc-based app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In a document based Cocoa app (Apples TextEdit sample as base code) I need one separate window which must be initated at launchtime and closes when app terminates. This window should be in a separate NIB and accessible by a menu to hide and bring it to front again. 
I read about NSWindows and NSWindowcontrollers but did not find a proper solution for my mixed approach of a document based app with a permanent non-doc-window

So I have two questions on that approach :
1. How to init a non-doc window at launchtime ?
2. How to connect a menu with open/close action to that window ?

Comment: That's kinda of a big answer, and lots of code is required to achieve this.

Comment: Do you want something like the preferences window of TextEdit?

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for this hint, you saved my day. This is a good example to learn how a window is maintained. But how to make it visible at launch ? The flag in XCode doesn't have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my question myself :

Willeke pointed me to the right direction. The TextEdit preference window is similiar to what I want, so I looked in the TextEdit sample and followed the code. And the solution to second question (make the window visible at launch) was very simple too.

In the subclass of the windowController is this method :

```
- (id)init {
        self = [super initWithWindowNibName: @"sampleWindow"];
        if  (self) {
            [self showWindow:self];
        }
        return self ;
}
```

All I had to do is to call `showWindow:`

Now the window always opens when the app launches. Easy ...